# Finding the max in excel from the same ID

Tags: excel, max, grouping, pivot-table

So I have a table that looks like this:

[image: this]

I am trying to find the max date. So if a customer ID is 12431, I want to get the maximum date corresponding to that cust ID. There are multiple dates corresponding to each ID but I want the maximum date.

Ideally, I'd like two new columns like

```
CustomerID Date


12431      01/10/2010
```

I am not able to figure out the pivot or the formula that would do this. Would be grateful if someone could give me a hand.

Comment: Plenty of usefull websites that will explain this topic. One that is very clear: https://exceljet.net/formula/max-if-criteria-match. Please have a good search first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pivot table, with `customer` in the `ROWS` and `order_date` in the `VALUES`.

Select *Value Field Settings* (dropdown on Values field button) then choose to *Summarize value field by* `Max`